# Mosfet Switch not working as expected

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I try to switch a 12V non-inductive load drawing 400-500mA with a [IRF3708](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf3708pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355df7cf5193c) Logic-Level-MOSFET with the 5V from an Arduino. 
I am new to MOSFETs but I simply cannot find my mistake. I think I fried some MOSFETs using the 5V because Rds(on) was too high (3-4Ohm) and this resulting in too much heat which killed the MOSFETs. I hope this conclusion is correct. 
But the datasheet states that at 4.5V Ugs Rds(on) should be in a 9.5-13.5mOhm range. Even if it may be optimistic I don't get why it is in the Ohm range and not even near the values in the datasheet.

What am I understanding wrong here?

**Schematic:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTeUnh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Circuit:**

[image: Circuit]
**Calculation of Rds(on)**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnbkp1.png)</sup>

With a load of 1k my Amperemeter gives me a current of 11.8mA @12V with 5V applied to the gate. This equals a series resistance of 1.0166kOhm. This results in a Rds(on) of 1.66Ohm. Ok it is lower than my wrong measuring but still a lot higher as in the datasheet. If 500mA would flow like in my application this  Rds(on) gives an UDS of 0.664V which result in 265.6mW of heat at the MOSFET. Correct?

Comment: What kind of load is it? Is it inductive?

Comment: It is a LED strip. A inductor would need a diode I guess.

Comment: (1) Is the FET stuck open-circuit or short-circuit? (2) Did you measure the gate voltage? (3) Are your grounds connected correctly? (4) Add a photo. We might spot an error.

Comment: "Rds(on) was ... (3-4Ohm)" - how do you know this? Got any voltage and current measurements you can share?

Comment: Have you triple and quad checked the pin connections of the FET to make sure you have Gate, Source and Drain correct?

Comment: Check your ground routing too. Does the source voltage go up relative to the arduino ground when the arduino it trying to turn it on.

Comment: This question looks extremely familiar...

Comment: @Transistor (1) I don't understand what you exactly mean. (2) Yes, it is 5V. I even connected 3.3V and the 12V directly (which the gate should be capable of) but the resistance is always 3-4Ohms. (3) I, guess (edited Post). (4) see (3).

Comment: @BruceAbbott I connected my multimeter at drain and source to measure it. If this was wrong I also don't know what killed the other MOSFETs anymore except too high power dissipation.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I connected my multimeter at source and GND to measure the Rds(on). If this was wrong I also don't know what killed the other MOSFETs anymore except too high power dissipation.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Front-facing it should be G,D,S. This should be correct.

Comment: @KingDuken I guess something like this gets asked too often. I have searched around a bit. Sorry if it was doubled.

Comment: maybe it's an optical illusion, but it seems to me that, while the green wire (supposedly connected to the 5V out of the arduino) is connected to the gate, the white wire is not connected to the drain, but to the next row (source) and the black wire is connected to nothing. Could you check this? Can you make a closer picture?

Comment: "I connected my multimeter **at source and GND** to measure the Rds(on)." - ??? To measure RDSon you should connect a load with known current draw and measure voltage between Drain and Source, then calculate the resistance. To get an accurate measurement you should probe directly onto the FET leads (breadboards are notorious for having high-resistance connections).

Comment: @next-hack Yes it is one. I bent the pins in a unusual way that every pin has a row of space inbetween that you guys can see better.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Would a 1MOhm resistor fit?

Comment: Unless you paid over $50 for that 1k resistor, your assumptions about its precision are unfounded. And unless you paid well over $500 for your multimeter, your assumptions about its accuracy are also unfounded. With that setup, the only way you're going to get an Rds-on value that's even in the right order of magnitude is with a *much* lower R1 and *much* higher current.

Comment: "With a load of 1k my Amperemeter gives me a current of 11.8mA @12V with 5V applied to the gate. This equals a series resistance of 1.0166kOhm. This results in a Rds(on) of 1.66Ohm." - Don't try to calculate the total series resistance, as this requires extreme measurement accuracy. Measure voltage between Drain and Source and calculate Rdson =  Vds / Id. To avoid robbing the Gate of voltage dropped across the ammeter, wire the meter in series with the load and FET Drain, not the Source.

Comment: @brhans I don't want to be extremely precise or accurate. It should be an approximation. Just to differ if Rds(on) is in mOhm or Ohm. For this my hardware should be enough, right?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I will edit this as soon as possible today and write a new comment as push for you. Thank you for your help btw :)

Comment: No - with that setup the best you should expect is an answer which is approximately accurate in the 10's of ohms range. Nowhere near the milli-ohms you're looking for. Your R1 really needs to be not much more than 10-20 x your expected Rds-on to be able to fudge away the resistor & measurement inaccuracies.

Comment: And what about @BruceAbbott 's method? Is it then some more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is correct.  Your way of measuring the R<sub>DSON</sub> is not.

> With a load of 1k my Amperemeter gives me a current of 11.8mA @12V

This is good to see that the circuit is generally working, but you don't have anywhere near the accuracy to declare the R<sub>DSON</sub> result you do.  How accurate is the supply?  How accurate is the resistor?  What is the accuracy of the ammeter?  What is the resistance of the ammeter.

Note that small errors in the first three cause large errors in the R<sub>DSON</sub> conclusion.  And the resistance of the meter is likely significantly higher than R<sub>DSON</sub>.  Even if the other numbers were accurate enough, all you'd really be doing is measuring the meter resistance.

For example, let's work backwards what some of your measurements would need to be to indicate 0 R<sub>DSON</sub>.  The supply might only be 11.8 V.  That's only 1.7% below spec.  Is your supply really that accurate?  Right.  I didn't think so.  Or the resistor might be 1.017 kΩ instead of 1.000 kΩ.  That's only 1.7 % high.  What range of current is really running thru the ammeter when it says 11.8 mA?  A combination of errors under 1% is all it takes to make the computed R<sub>DSON</sub> actually come out negative!

Your measurements don't support your conclusions.

Answer (score -1):

You can't reliably test a MOSFET that way (using a multimeter).  For one, most multimeters wont put out 12V and the Vdd has to be higher than the gate voltage or you can damage the device.

Testing it in circuit is more reliable.  Understand that a MOSFET is not a voltage to resistance device, its is a voltage controlled current device.  The current it allows to flow from D-S is dependant on the gate to source voltage.  The resistance is dynamic, i.e. it is whatever it needs to be to pass the rated current for the given voltage.    If you use a multimeter though, it will have a current limited output which means you will only get so much current and the effective resistance will be the same no matter the gate voltage.

Comment: Ok I will calculate the Rds(on) with a resistive load. You say it is a "voltage controlled current device and the resistance is what it needs to pass the rated current for the given voltage". But wouldn't that mean that more/or maybe too much power gets lost at the MOSFET?

Comment: Not necessarily, the device is fully off if the gate voltage is 0v.  The typical off resistance is in the megohm range.  9.5 megohms for that device.  The electric field generated by the gate charge induces charge carriers to move from the Drain to the source.  There is very little current flow from the gate to either the  drain or source.  The voltage on the gate is what determines the strength of the electric field and how much of the channel is passivated.   The more of the channel is passivated, the more charge carriers are allowed to flow.

Comment: Ok thats also what we learned in theory lessons. But in my understanding that means that a MOSFET is never generating waste heat which is not true. Sorry for asking so much but I am really a beginner with "real" hardware not just drawn circuits.

Comment: *"Vdd has to be higher than the gate voltage or you can damage the device"*.  This is just plain wrong. *"a MOSFET is not a voltage to resistance device, its is a voltage controlled current device"*.  This is true over part of its operating range, but not when used as a fully-on switch.  In that case, D-S *does* look like a resistor.  That's what the Rdson spec is all about.